# CouchDb Post Query using complex key in combination with keys payload

Tags: post, key, couchdb

Say I have documents with fields type and created. I want to get documents from x types and specified date.

I have this map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.Program) {
    emit([doc.Type, doc.Created], doc);
  }
}
```

I have tried post request with body like so:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "sometype",
        "anothertype"
    ]
}
```

That works fine, but how to add Created? Attempt at pseudocode:

```
{
    "keys": [
        [
            "sometype",
            "2014-02-10"
        ],
        [
            "someothertype",
            "2014-02-10"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried what you've shown? If so, what do you get?

Comment: Receive nothing in return.

Comment: What does a GET against your view with no `key` or `startkey` parameter give you?